# Load two / several MS Access Table into C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, connection-string

I´m asking how to connect two or more tables from an MS Access table into c# Windows forms?.

I get the error, that ue cant find the second table:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
    private OleDbConnection connection2 = new OleDbConnection();
    public Form1()
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\be\Documents\MitarbeiterDaten2.accdb;
        Persist Security Info=False;";

        connection2.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\be\Documents\DatenbankAbteilung.accdb;
        Persist Security Info=False;";
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = "select ABTEILUNG from combo";
            command.CommandText = query;

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Abteilung.Items.Add(reader["ABTEILUNG"].ToString());
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Anybody got an solution?
Its just about, how to connect two or more MS Access tables into C# Windows forms.

Answer (score 2):

You can reuse the the objects, and can get data from various tables or databases, as :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = "select ABTEILUNG from combo";
            command.CommandText = query;

            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Abteilung.Items.Add(reader("ABTEILUNG").ToString());
            }
            reader.Close(); //' Always Close ther Reader. Don't left it open

            connection2.Open();
            command.Connection = connection2; //' Reusing Same Command Over New Connection
            command.CommandText = "Select Field2 from Table2";
            while (reader.Read)
            {
                if (!(Convert.IsDBNull(reader("Field2")))) //' Checking If Null Value is there
                {
                    Abteilung.Items.Add(reader("Field2").ToString());
                }
            }
            reader.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
            connection2.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the database is same and you want to access data from Two Tables or more tables then, you don't need two Connection. You can use two or more commands for accessing data from same Database.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `using` blocks to take care of the commands and connections and then using `DataAdapter` to get the job done easily. I use some code like this.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(MDBConnection.ConnectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Column FROM Table1", con))
    {
        using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
    }

    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT AnotherColumn FROM Table2", con))
    {
        using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
    }
}
return ds;
```

Comment: You are initializing commands two two times in code above, which will decrease the performance of application